# How to get element from jsonb with a path array

Tags: postgresql

I have a function, that takes a json path as an array, and a jsonb as arguments.

Is there a function that gets the element in the jsonb document by means of the path array?

Say something like:
`get_jsonb_element(my_jsonb, my_path)`

Where jsonb could be:

```
{
  "a": 
  {
    "b":"x"
  }
}
```

And path could be:

```
'{a,b}'
```

And the function would return 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
The operator
`#>`
does it.
E.g.

```
my_element = my_jsonb #>> my_path
```